# xsd:import inside an Embedded Resource XSD

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xsd, embedded-resource

I have a Class Library project which houses some shared code between other projects in my solution.  One of these pieces of shared code involves **running an XML validation** against an XSD file.  The name of the XSD is passed as a parameter to the method and then loaded using `Assembly.GetFile()`.

The problem is that the XSD file **imports two other XSDs**.  I've loaded all three as Resources within my Class Library but from what I've read the xsd:import is not going to work.  Is there an alternative approach to making these XSDs available within my Class Library Project without breaking the `xsd:import` statements?

**Edit - Update**

I implemented [Alexander's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331849/xsdimport-inside-an-embedded-resource-xsd/5336148#5336148) below but as I stated in my comment, whenever `GetEntity()` is called for an `xs:import`'d XSD, `ofObjectToReturn` is `null`.  This caused the first instance of an `xs:import`'d type to throw an exception "type not defined."

In an effort to resolve this issue I altered `GetEntity()` to return `GetManifestResourceStream()` regardless of `ofObjectToReturn`'s value.  This now seems to work for the first level of `xs:import` statements but a secondary `xs:import` inside one of the original `xs:import` XSDs is not working.  I've confirmed that `GetEntity()` is being called for this secondary `xs:import` but I'm receiving the "type not defined" exception for a type defined within this secondary XSD.

- TopLevel.xsd - *types resolve fine*

  - FirstLevelImport1.xsd - *types resolve fine*
  - FirstLevelImport2.xsd - *types resolve fine*

    - SecondLevelImport1.xsd - *"type not defined" exception thrown for type defined in this XSD*

The "type not defined" exception is thrown during `XmlReader.Create()` that is passed the `XmlReaderSettings` defining the schema validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the files, which are added by either `xsd:import` or `xsd:include` you can use a custom **XmlResolver**. You can find an example of an **ResourceXmlResolver** below. It assumes, that the assembly's name is "*AYez.EmbeddedXsdTests*".

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace AYez.EmbeddedXsdTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class EmbeddedXsdTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void SomeEntryPoint()
        {
            var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet {XmlResolver = new ResourceXmlResolver()};
            schemaSet.Add("rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/financial/v1_0/financial.xsd", @"Invoice.xsd");
            schemaSet.Compile();

            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema, Schemas = schemaSet };

            settings.ValidationEventHandler += delegate(object o, ValidationEventArgs e)
            {
                switch (e.Severity)
                {
                    case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                        Console.Write("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                        break;
                    case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                        Console.Write("Warning: {0}", e.Message);
                        break;
                }
            };
            var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"d:\temp\Invoice.xml", settings);
            while (xmlReader.Read()) { /*TODO: Nothing*/} // Validation is performed while reading

        }
    }

    public class ResourceXmlResolver: XmlResolver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, maps a URI to an object containing the actual resource.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A System.IO.Stream object or null if a type other than stream is specified.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="absoluteUri">The URI returned from <see cref="M:System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(System.Uri,System.String)"/>. </param><param name="role">The current version does not use this parameter when resolving URIs. This is provided for future extensibility purposes. For example, this can be mapped to the xlink:role and used as an implementation specific argument in other scenarios. </param><param name="ofObjectToReturn">The type of object to return. The current version only returns System.IO.Stream objects. </param><exception cref="T:System.Xml.XmlException"><paramref name="ofObjectToReturn"/> is not a Stream type. </exception><exception cref="T:System.UriFormatException">The specified URI is not an absolute URI. </exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="absoluteUri"/> is null. </exception><exception cref="T:System.Exception">There is a runtime error (for example, an interrupted server connection). </exception>
        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {   
                // If ofObjectToReturn is null, then any of the following types can be returned for correct processing:
                // Stream, TextReader, XmlReader or descendants of XmlSchema
                var result =  this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("AYez.EmbeddedXsdTests.{0}",
                                                                                             Path.GetFileName(absoluteUri.ToString())));                
                // set a conditional breakpoint "result==null" here
                return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, sets the credentials used to authenticate Web requests.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// An <see cref="T:System.Net.ICredentials"/> object. If this property is not set, the value defaults to null; that is, the XmlResolver has no user credentials.
        /// </returns>
        public override ICredentials Credentials
        {
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever `GetEntity()` is called for an `xsl:import`'d schema, `ofObjectToReturn` is `null` and thus I am receiving an exception stating the imported types are not defined.

Comment: You're right. Just remove the `if` statement in that particular scenario. Normally, we should check the `ofObjectToReturn` parameter and return an object of the same type.

Comment: ...However, if it is `null` one of the following should be returned: `Stream`, `TextReader`, `XmlReader` or descendants of `XmlSchema`. I found it out after examining the source code of .NET framework's System.Xml. :)

Comment: **Just noticed your update:** I had the same exception, while not all xsd files were included as resources into the assembly. You can simply check it, when you set a conditional breakpoint onto `return` in `GetEntity`

Comment: I'd tried using the `ResourceXmlResolver` example from above, but the gives me the following error when the `Compile()` method of my `XmlSchemaSet` is called: _The simpleType 'customersTypes:ValidCustomerTypes' has already been declared._ 

Obviously "customersTypes:ValidCustomerTypes" is specific to my case, as I'm trying to import an XSD-file that has restrictions on allowed customer types...

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be fixed if we first read the xsd files into string variable.

e.g.

```
var stream =assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.child.xsd");
```

now use stream reader to read this into string

e.g.

```
string childXSD=new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

similary get string ParentXSD
Then use

```
var xmlReader=XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(childXSD)));
schemaCollection.Add(null,xmlReader);
var xmlReader=XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(parentXSD)));
schemaCollection.Add(null,xmlReader);
```

I think sequence of child to parent is important as we are referencing child XSD into parent.